# Openwrt hardware nat bypass implications

Tags: networking, router, security, nat, openwrt

### My setup

ISP provided router (the gateway) on a 1Gbit/100Mbit fiber line and an openwrt router (the router). The gateway does not support bridge mode so I followed the guide for [Poor's man bridge mode](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/wan/dmz-based-bridge-mode), i.e. setup the router as a DMZ host on the gateway and connect it to the wan interface on the router (doing double nat).

### The problem

The problem is that since openwrt does not do hardware nat I am only getting arround 270Mbit speed with sirq going very high (and I guess causes other performance problems).

### The workarround

I do not have admin access to the gateway but the gateway supports adding a second IP. So I set an IP from the internal network and connected another cable to the gateway from the router's lan, essentially bridging the two networks (wan & lan), and changed the default route in openwrt to the gateway's IP from the internal network. Now hosts on the internal network can reach up to 1gbit speed as outgoing traffic flows through the gateway as the router acts as a switch.

For incoming traffic I have made sure to mark incoming packets so they are routed back from the wan interface, thus exposed services work correctly.

### Security(?)

My question is what are the security risks with the above setup (if any). Since incoming traffic will flow from the gateway to the router's wan interface (as it is setup as a DMZ host), the router's firewall will protect the internal network. I do not see a way how the gateway can be hacked, but even if it did, what difference would it made in case I did not use the router but only the provided ISP equipment, i.e. the gateway?